# "Command Not Found" error in developemnt of VS Code Extension (due to require axios line)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a VS Code Extension following the simple [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5V4T3o3CXE&t=4s) tutorial. The Extension works well and dialogue box appears in th starting, but when I add the axios packages and the code for it, it gives command not found error in the Developer Window.

Pic: [Error msg command not found in VSC extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR6Tw.png)

Here is the `extension.js` (you can ignore the implementation):

```js
const vscode = require("vscode")
const axios = require("axios")
const xmlParser = require("fast-xml-parser")

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
async function activate(context) {
  const res = await axios.get("https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/rss.xml")
  const articles = xmlParser.parse(res.data).rss.channel.item.map(article => {
    return {
      label: article.title,
      detail: article.description,
      link: article.link,
    }
  })

  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "wds-search-blog-example.searchWdsBlogExample",
    async function () {
      const article = await vscode.window.showQuickPick(articles, {
        matchOnDetail: true,
      })

      if (article == null) return

      vscode.env.openExternal(article.link)
    }
  )

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable)
}
exports.activate = activate

function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
  activate,
  deactivate,
}
```

And `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "wds-blog-search",
    "displayName": "WDS Blog Search",
    "description": "Search Web Dev Simplified's Blog For Articles",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "publisher": "WebDevSimplified",
    "repository": {
        "url": "https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/vscode-extension-blog-searcher"
    },
    "icon": "logo.png",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.52.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:wds-blog-search.searchWdsBlog"
    ],
    "main": "./extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "wds-blog-search.searchWdsBlog",
                "title": "Search WDS Blog"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "pretest": "npm run lint",
        "test": "node ./test/runTest.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.52.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.1.3",
        "@types/mocha": "^8.0.4",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.7",
        "eslint": "^7.15.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.6",
        "mocha": "^8.1.3",
        "typescript": "^4.1.2",
        "vscode-test": "^1.4.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "fast-xml-parser": "^3.17.6"
    }
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/vscode-extension-blog-searcher

There are no syntax errors as far as I know. Tried on another system but still got the same issue. Not able to understand what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did anyone find a solution for this? Do we need to change to some other library instead of Axios?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `.default` on the `require`. Like this:

```js
const axios = require("axios").default;
```

***But I ALSO had to completely trash the project and start over.*** Because even after removing all my changes and restoring the hello-world back to its original state, it was STILL broken. Whatever axios did, it did it for good.

So yeah, 2 things.

1. trash the project and start from a new one
2. append `.default` to your `require()`

I don't know why the youtuber was able to get away with not invoking `.default`. Maybe something changed in axios recently?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same video and got a very similar error:

```
Command 'Hello World' resulted in an error (command 'wds-search-blog-example.helloWorld' not found)
```

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.wds-search-blog-example' failed: connect EACCES :443.
```

After examining the error message from `axios.get()` wrapped in `try...catch`, I received the following information:

```
Z_BUF_ERROR
```

```
Error: unexpected end of file
 Function.from (d:\\wds\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:785:14)
 BrotliDecompress.handleStreamError (d:\\wds\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:2696:29)
 BrotliDecompress.emit (node:events:538:35)
 emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
 emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
 process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)'
```

I was able to solve this by adding a header with the encoding to the query (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735197/14928633)):

```js
const axios = reqiure('axios');
//...
async function activate(context) {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/rss.xml",
    { headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" } }
  )
  //...
}
```

I use axios 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of debuggibg, heres how I solved it:
*I consulted [The npm package store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser)*

```
const res = await axios.get('https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/rss.xml',
    { headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" } });
const { XMLParser} = require("fast-xml-parser");

const parser = new XMLParser();
let data = parser.parse(res.data).rss.channel.item;
console.log(data[0]);
```