# getting "unexpected end of file" axios error while making a get request in this small nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have been getting this error in this small nodejs app while trying to learn using axios on the backend to make request. "unexpected end of file".

### axios request file

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getData = async () => {
  let data;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    );
    console.log(response);
    data = response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return;
  }
  return data;
};
```

### server.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from 'cors';
import axios from "axios";
import { getData } from "./utils/getData.js";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    let users;
    users = await getData();
    res.send(users); 
})


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server listening at port 5000");
})
```

Comment: Not sure why it happens, but if you use http instead of https you can return response.data

Comment: thanks for help. I was stuck on this for long time. It works

Answer (score 57):

You can add below header encoding to your request.

```
axios.get("url", { 
    headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" } 
});
```

Comment: So the **reason** this helps is because it tells the server what encoding(s) you want returned.

Comment: yea it's a new error that is common with Axios version =< 1.2.0, read on the issues here - https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5346

Answer (score 6):

the Brotli decompression bug was fixed in [v1.2.2](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/1.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Bro, go to Package.json--> in dependencies --> check for axios ---> Add 'axios' : '1.1.3'.

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).